# How to embbed images in jekyll-built blog with 'brocks' package

Tags: html, r, jekyll, knitr

Following the steps of Brendan on this post https://brendanrocks.com/blogging-with-rmarkdown-knitr-jekyll/ I was able to successfully build my blog using knitr-jekyll and R markdown. However when it comes to embedding images on the .Rmd I am having a lot of trouble. The post output does not show any images embedded (just the plots produced by coding).

I tried using knitr::include_graphics() and also pure HTML  tags (both ways directly in the .Rmd file) but got only empty spaces.

Thinking about the possibility of the problem being with paths I tried to move images to the figure/source folder but got nothing. Then I tried moving to a new folder called _data and adjusting the path on include_graphics() but got nothing again.

OS: Ubuntu 16.04

Current code with include_graphics():

````
```{r, out.width="900px", echo=FALSE}
knitr::include_graphics("path_root_site/_data/engrenagem.png")
```

```{r, out.width="900px", echo=FALSE}
knitr::include_graphics("path_root_site/_data/engrenagem2.png")
```
````

current code with pure HTML (another image):

```
<a href="http://sage.saude.gov.br/lib/svg2img.php?w=1795&h=250"><img src="path_root_site/_data/canvas.png" alt="gráfico sage" width=1000 height=500></img></a>
```